# Swift: Button with image bigger than button

Tags: swift, uibutton

I can't figure out a way to make a button look like in the following image.

[image: image of the button]

The icon is supposed to be bigger than the button.

I already tired this, but it doesn't work:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "CircleForButtonCountries")
goToCoutriesButtonMain.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
goToCoutriesButtonMain.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Don’t make the image bigger than the button. Put them both onto a view and make the button smaller than the image. You won’t be able to (easily) use a standard button with the setImage method.

Comment: and then make the view a button so that I can click it?

Comment: there's no default way to achieve this. you'll have to design a custom view that at max should include a base `UIView`, a `UIButton` in the center and finally a big `UIImageView` on top of the button with a nice big white border and rounded corners. Try this or something else and **then** get back to us

Comment: You don’t need to make it a button. You could add a tap gesture recogniser to it though. :-) or you could use a button like staticVoidMan said :-) there are many ways to achieve it. Try playing around in a playground for some quick experimentation.

Comment: The idea with the view worked pretty good, thank you very much.
If I have 2 buttons would you put them in the same view oder make 2 views and put them together in a stack?
I know there are many possibilities but sometimes one works better than the other

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
let image = UIImage(named: "CircleForButtonCountries")
goToCoutriesButtonMain.imageView?.contentMode = 
UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
goToCoutriesButtonMain.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)  // use setBackgroundImage instead of setImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in Swift 5:

```
yourButton.clipsToBounds = true
yourButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
yourButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "yourImage"), for: .normal)
```